# Remove rows in pandas dataframe based on index labels

Tags: python, pandas

I have defined a list as: name=[1, 5, 8, 10, 11, 20].
How to remove the rows from a dataframe specific to Index Labels for the numbers given in the list?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Answer (score 0):

You can remove rows from a data frame specific to Index by using `drop`. That can accept Index as a *named list*, like this:

**Note**:  ‘*ignore*’, suppress error and only existing labels are dropped.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape(25, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

name=[1, 5, 8, 10, 11, 20]
df=df.drop(name, errors='ignore')
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
     A   B   C   D
0    0   1   2   3
2    8   9  10  11
3   12  13  14  15
4   16  17  18  19
6   24  25  26  27
7   28  29  30  31
9   36  37  38  39
12  48  49  50  51
13  52  53  54  55
14  56  57  58  59
15  60  61  62  63
16  64  65  66  67
17  68  69  70  71
18  72  73  74  75
19  76  77  78  79
21  84  85  86  87
22  88  89  90  91
23  92  93  94  95
24  96  97  98  99
```